# Why is Minspantree() function not working well?

Tags: matlab, tree, nodes

so Im trying to apply minspantree function o a graph, choosing my own Root but its not working. Whichever root Im choosing its not working

Here is the code.

```matlab
x = findnode(graph, num2str(IP_indices(i)))
T = minspantree(graph, 'Root', findnode(graph, num2str(IP_indices(i))));
```

Also, uploading an example. Here the root should be 702 but it’s not. No matter which one I try to use as root, the same tree will be displayed

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or its just the function not working well?

Comment: What do you expect? You’re getting *the* minimum spanning tree, it’s going to be the same no matter what start node is used in the computation.

Comment: But since I´m setting 'x' as a root, shouldnt the root be displayed at top of the tree? I mean, if setting a root won´t change anything why is this even an option in this function?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.minspantree.html#buofm4y-1-Root — it’s used in the computation, but it doesn’t affect subsequent display. A tree is just a graph without cycles. If you want to display it as a tree with a specific node as the root, you might need to explicitly call the display function.

Comment: Maybe `plot(graph,'Layout','layered')`? Not sure, seems you need a directed graph for that, I don’t know what your data is like.

Comment: X and Y for each node in the plot can be explicitly determined by the "XData" and "YData" switch, so you could have total control of your graph. Probably try different layout options first then modify as necessary.